# Is there a way to Change the checkout directory in teamcity based on which buildAgent is running the build?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I have two build agents running for teamcity. One build agent runs on a server with a d drive on it and one runs on a server that does not have a D drive. I want the buildAgent on the server with the d drive to do an svn checkout to a specified file location on the d drive and the second build agent that runs on a server that does not have a d drive in it to do it to a specified file location on the c drive of that server. Is this doable?

Comment: If you don't specify checkout folder. TC agent will create and use sub-folder in working folder from config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a `CHECKOUT_DIR` environment variable on both machines. I then use those environment variables in team city by saying to put the checked out files in the `%env.CHECKOUT_DIR%\app\trunk` directory